# How to update AppCompat?

Tags: java, android

Hi currently new to Android Studio and Java. Attempting to use the design dependency to create floating labels for a login application. However, I require 'com.android.support.AppCompat-7:26.1.0' minimum.

I current have 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'. I am just unsure how i update or change this. I am using minimum API of Android 10. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Video tutorial example:]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoGLX.png): [image: My dependancy code]

Comment: `com.android.support.AppCompat-7:26.1.0` is old. why you want older version ?

Comment: Can you share your code to know where you stuck?

Comment: androidx is newer than support lib. Don't look just at the version numbers

Comment: and if you still want older version, then inside your Gradle (App module) you can set  `targetSdkVersion 26` and also if you have  `compileSdkVersion` also then set it to 26 as well

Comment: If you require "com.android.support.AppCompat-7:26.1.0" use the AndroidX version because it's newer and offers the same features of the legacy support libraries. If you plan on pushing the app to the Play Store you need to at least target SDK level 28.

Comment: I require a minimum level fo 26 as used in the tutorial I am referencing however the newer the better I imagine. So if i set the targetSdkVersion that should change it?

Comment: Just so i understand AndroidX version 1 is newer than Android support lIbraries (E.G. Version26)?

Comment: @Jack1999 "AndroidX version 1 is newer than Android support lIbraries (E.G. Version26)?" this is correct.  By "minimum API of Android 10" are you referring to API level 10 (Android 2.3.3) or API level 29 (Android 10)?

Comment: API 29 (Android 10)